# Dropbox context menu not showing all options

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

this is a problem I'm only having on my Windows 10 computer, but I'm seeming to not get the full context menu for any of my files. I'm looking in particular for the Online-only/Local option, but the only context menu action I'm seeing is Send a copy and that doesn't even work.

[image]

I've tried restarting Dropbox to no avail. I can't seem to find anything online about this either; is there anything I could do about this?

Comment: To get a menu like this, I need to open Dropbox which in turn open a Windows File Explorer window. So these should be Windows Explorer context menus.  Thai is how it works on my system.

Comment: oh wow, that actually amazingly works! I've literally never realized this, and I don't need to do this on my win11 computer oddly enough; just have to open the full context menu. much appreciated! if you want to put this into an answer I could accept

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a menu like this, I need to open Dropbox (double click on it) which in turn opens a Windows File Explorer window.

So then there should be Windows Explorer context menus. This is how it works on my system.

Windows Explorer has a context menu so this should work.

I am using Windows 11 as well.

Comment: sounds good! works for me, although for my computer any Explorer instance will give me the options. on my win10 computer, I do need to do this, which works

Comment: The contexts are different in Windows 11 from Windows 10 but I have been able to make both systems work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're opening a dropbox directory through a symlink/junction. Sometimes dropbox sets things up this way. The workaround of opening the dropbox-which-in-turn-opens-an-explorer-window causes you to access dropbox not-through-a-junction, and so the full context menu appears.